# How does a group element work in an XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML Schema that mostly makes sense, but I encountered a bit that I don't understand. Below is a snapshot of the schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="DATA-FIELD">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="FIELD-CONTENT" />
        <xs:element name="Field" type="FIELD" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="FIELD">
    <xs:group ref="FIELD-CONTENT" />
    <xs:attribute name="att" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="FIELD-CONTENT">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Elem" type="ELEM" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Mostly what I don't understand is how the group element is being used, and what a sample XML file that adheres to this schema would look like? Would it look like this:

```
<DataField>
    <Field att="test">
        <Elem>element</Elem>
    </Field>
</DataField>
```

OR

```
<DataField>
    <Elem>element</Elem>
</DataField>
```

Comment: Your missing an element definition for `DataField` and a type definition for `ELEM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group element represents a fragment of a content model, and is largely used to represent common parts of multiple elements. In your example, it's used to encapsulate the option `Elem` field in both the `DATA-FIELD` and `FIELD` types. In most cases, you can substitute the contents of the group element for the group references to get an idea of what the schema is accomplishing:

```
<xs:complexType name="DATA-FIELD">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Elem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Field" type="FIELD" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="FIELD">
    <xs:element name="Elem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:attribute name="att" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

In terms of validation, both the instance documents you specified are valid given the schema, since both elements are optional. In the first instance document the `Elem` field from the group is omitted, while in the second case the `Field` field is omitted. The following would also be legal documents given this schema:

```
<DataField>
    <Elem>foo</Elem>
    <Field att="test">
        <Elem>element</Elem>
    </Field>
</DataField>
```

And:

```
<DataField/>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing that up. Makes much more sense now.